# MySQL Query is returning additional results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that returns `lastName` from `customers` table, `bidAmount` and `bidTime` from `bids` table and `productName` from `product` table on a certain day. The bid table has both `custom.customerID` and `product.productID` as foreign keys so it can access the related data. The query I have written is

```
SELECT lastName, bidAmount, bidTime, productName 
FROM product, customer, bids 
WHERE bidTime BETWEEN '06/19/2014 12:00:01 AM' AND '06/19/2014 11:59:59 PM';
```

but for some reason it is returning a copy of every bid in the time frame for every customer in the database, rather than just the customer who places the bid.

I hope this is all making sense, I can explain in more detail if need be.

the tables in question are 
`customer`
`bids`
`product`

`bids` has `customer.customerID` and `product.productID` as foreign keys
`product` has `customer.customerID` as a foreign key

so as far as I know it should all connect appropriately. or am I overlooking something.

Comment: You need explicit joins, how tables are related show the complete DDL for all the tables.

Comment: hi @AbhikChakraborty pease see the edit in the question as for how the tables are connected

Comment: It is a Cartesian product, you should use explicit `JOINS` with `ON` clause.

Comment: thanks guys, I'm still learning SQL and I forgot all about joins! back to studying for me i think thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to explicitly join the tables together - at the moment, your query is implicitly Cartesian-joining the tables. Try something like:

```
SELECT c.lastName, b.bidAmount, b.bidTime, p.productName 
FROM bids b
join product p on b.product_id = p.product_id
join customer c on b.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE bidTime BETWEEN '06/19/2014 12:00:01 AM' AND '06/19/2014 11:59:59 PM'
```

Comment: that worked! thanks heaps @Mark Bannister, im still studying SQL and completely forgot about joins!